# C# robust key pair match

Tags: c#, key, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, robust

I'm generating a key pair in this way

```cs
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
_privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
_publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
```

If we do a simple Console.Write(_publicKey) we have

```
    <RSAKeyValue>
      <Modulus>nW/DERb839Z6fM594Eg3Y3AnpEKjMP/QzGn/iJW9snGkIl3crsa6a+g8S7uKNM0rBNoIdYnMlJTRDoPBpl35eO+ad/V0K9CJ+AqAo4q2pVEsJJujjhNX0C6wwrocS5vGWnuX02JZzVwiQxailo0qdq0qYLhp2ckQLUfwGxWr1mU=</Modulus>
      <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    </RSAKeyValue>
```

If we do a simple Console.Write(_privateKey)

```
    <RSAKeyValue>
      <Modulus>nW/DERb839Z6fM594Eg3Y3AnpEKjMP/QzGn/iJW9snGkIl3crsa6a+g8S7uKNM0rBNoIdYnMlJTRDoPBpl35eO+ad/V0K9CJ+AqAo4q2pVEsJJujjhNX0C6wwrocS5vGWnuX02JZzVwiQxailo0qdq0qYLhp2ckQLUfwGxWr1mU=</Modulus>
      <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
      <P>wrI5ll8sm45OI+jGNVombQB9YUMMzlHgiP//q8N6shYDkmaGrijYrM0/xm9mXn8sxTvg+jX55159Mpuk1rIiBw==</P>
      <Q>zwIriOVyG45A3i3UHQt+KijTz1kSw+m03Fbw3WDbh2ooYewCvLoLFWCsgk1TeXfMK5u7dLdttgGqC27qd6i5Mw==</Q>
      <DP>JL4dwBMWCAVDGePEBC2PMuL0xnYw5H7vMOufBHtPnGwrIGXY5OUwfuv9LSW42/yEJnS2cIHfN5rNZc+ZvCrB4Q==</DP>
      <DQ>aL53WtCGeWz0Y7easYukLh70deFjPmBd1HPlco7U5eMQReQOyoH0o7+D6nbH+xlj5Njq9DbwO30CFsDrwNpNww==</DQ>
      <InverseQ>OV9TPLS5fli7K59hGH1m5ZnTT80UY9XJzKRFRjWuDHI1P7QL+d6+1d08DAICDWTu6ac/1jD8ibmO6AxOmYw6OQ==</InverseQ>
      <D>kiQjm+KN2645R09as2311F1Qvv6Ig7yDcqzWYlA1pcYtiSU97BNXC0GpbtdohHkK/Nbz0T+X4zh9Ew8lHCzRnIdSQZwGyeCXmk8QNvzK3HTOmLgaTu6UaNFtilqgYWzXHuu8WtvWyyN5F3bLb+PYJ1hAMCrS1RxOqlxXczgSqQU=</D>
    </RSAKeyValue>
```

I want to check if the two keys, once generated and saved, are matching.

As we know anyone has access to the public key.

ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf

For what I read, to check if a private and public key are of the same pair we verify that the Modulus is the same and that Exponent of the public key is equal to PublicExponent of the private key

If I take the public key and I do:

```
    <RSAKeyValue>
      <Modulus>nW/DERb839Z6fM594Eg3Y3AnpEKjMP/QzGn/iJW9snGkIl3crsa6a+g8S7uKNM0rBNoIdYnMlJTRDoPBpl35eO+ad/V0K9CJ+AqAo4q2pVEsJJujjhNX0C6wwrocS5vGWnuX02JZzVwiQxailo0qdq0qYLhp2ckQLUfwGxWr1mU=</Modulus>
      <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
      <P>Hi-guys==</P>
      <Q>Im-doing-something-nasty==</Q>
      <DP>to-pass==</DP>
      <DQ>the-key-check==</DQ>
      <InverseQ>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==</InverseQ>
      <D>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY=</D>
    </RSAKeyValue>
```

As you can see, if I consider only the modulus and exponent, this private key match the public key (!).

Considering that a text is encrypted with the public key, and decrypted with the private key, is clear that no one can decrypt a message with this forged key. So, a forged key like this, is useless.

I'm just wondering, if there is something else to do for a robust key pair match.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem (or the use case for that matter). Why would you forge your private key? How would anyone else forge your private key (it should be kept private for a reason)? -- Btw. the Modulus of your public key example doesn't match the Modulus of the private key example(s). The public key should basically be the private key without the private information, right?

Comment: You could hash the private key and compare the hashes... but if someone can forge/modify your private key, they are likely also able to change the hash... So again, in what scenario does someone have access to change/forge your private key?

Comment: You question is not clear, and it sounds to me like you have not clear how RSA is working. The xml that you sent is wrong, the modulus of the private and of the public key have to be the same.

Comment: Checking if the XML-formatted public and private keys "match" is easy, as you've noted. Checking if the private key is consistent and correct is also easy, but rather tedious. Just look at the definition of the components and check that p*q = modulus, 1<p<modulus, and so forth for each component. But note that this should never happen in practice.

Comment: "no one can decrypt a message with this forged key. So, a forged key like this, is useless." -- That sounds like intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JamesKPolk Imagine a scenario where the server contains all the public keys.

To check if the two keys are matching, the server use the public key of a user to encrypt the hash of a phrase chosen randomly

The server send the encrypted hash to the client

The client decrypt the hash with his private key

The client send the decrypted hash to the server

If the hash is the same of the one used initially, and we repeat the proof multiple times, we have a key match.

On client side I can also check the consistency of the private key, in the way you suggested.